# What are options to change datatype of GCP Big Query ( BQ) large table column type to a NON coercible datatype

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

Hello GCP and Big Query experts, I have a large GCP Big Query (BQ) table . I need to change the datatype of one column in that table from INT64 to STRING.

For that I first referred to [BQ conversion rules](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules)

As per that I could have used BQ DDL to make a change in column datatype if the change is to a “coercible” data type, But since datatype change from INT64 to STRING is NOT  “coercible”  I cannot use DDL ... alas

Predictably when I tried the ddl anyways ignoring this knowledge I get error.
I tried following DDL

```
Alter table my_bq_dataset.my_bq_table alter column my_int_column set data type STRING;
```

Executing this gives an error as below

```
 “ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE requires that the existing column type (INT64) is assignable to the new type (STRING) at [1:49]”
```

So Based on more reading of BQ documentation  [GCP documentation on modyfying table schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#cast_a_columns_data_type) I understand that another possible option is to export  table data to Cloud Storage, and then load the data into a new table with the modified schema .

For that I did following

1. I exported my BQ table data to a bucket in zipped csv format to gs://export-bucket/my-export-file-zipped-csv
2. I attempted an import by a simple load using following steps
   Used a create table option ( by clicking on my BQ dataset) with following options

- Selected the file from the Cloud Storage bucket that I exported before ( gs://export-bucket/my-export-file-zipped-csv )
- Selected CSV for file format
- Set table type to “Native Table”
- Checked “Edit as text” schema option - and I provided a json schema schema with the definition of column changed to string ( see below snippet)

  {
  "mode": "REQUIRED",
  "name": "pubsub_event_id",
  "type": "STRING"
  },

However The attempt to create table thus failed  with error as below

```
 “Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'my_column' as INT64 for field my_column'(position 0) starting at location 0 with message 'Unable to parse' File: gs://export-bucket/my-export-file-zipped-csv
```

So my request is to suggest a suitable method to change the column definition.

Would I have to use Extract Transform Load type of operation and what does BQ provide for that ?

Sincere thanks for your help

Yogesh

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution

1. Add a new column to the table with a datatype of STRING
2. Populate that STRING column using an UPDATE statement that casts the INT64 column’s value
3. Drop the INT64 column
4. Rename the STRING column to the INT64 column’s name

Comment: Hi  NickW  - Thanks for your response -  I had considered casting before - I however desisted from that as I read  Casting   and overwriting is not recommended for very large tables because it requires a full table scan.    In your step - "Step 2 - Populate that STRING column using an UPDATE statement that casts the INT64 column’s value" you suggest I resort to casting . I understand that this casting does not involve an overwrite and may not need a "full table scan: - but can you share thoughts on how expensive is casting and is it recommended for very large tables ?

Comment: Particularly as this is a one-off operation, I’m not sure why you care about the cost? In any case, if you want to change the column type then this is the way to do it and it costs whatever it costs

Comment: Thanks - I will go ahead and try and post the results here